# CloudKit Separate Developer ID and Testing ID

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I have 2 AppleID's.  One I use for development and the other for all other iCloud related activity, mail, address book, iCloud Drive etc...

I am trying to test in the simulator, an App developed to use CloudKit.

Xcode has my developer ID of course, and the simulator is signed into my other general use Apple ID.  When I run my App and try to create a custom private database zone (for use with sharing), it all runs fine.  But when I go to the dashboard to view my newly added records there is nothing there.  I sign into the  dashboard with my developer ID as signing with with my general use ID produces an error.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Rob

Comment: You can't see another users's private data in the CloudKit dashboard. Either sign in to the simulator with your developer ID or make your general ID a member of your developer team

Comment: I tried that.  When I signed into the simulator with my developer ID it produces an error when I try to create the custom zone saying  it couldn't get iCloudAuthToken from credential.  When I try to invite my general ID to my development team is says it's already on my team; although I don't see it in my list of team members.

Comment: Hmm. I have used multiple iCloud Id on the simulator without any issue. Can you sin in with your developer Id at iCloud.com?

Comment: Yes.  I am signed in on my Mac with my general ID if that makes a difference,

Comment: You need to use your developer id on the simulator. What is the exact CloudKit error?

Comment: I figured it out.  It's working now.  Looks like the developer ID didn't have iCloud Drive initially for some  reason.  Now it shows up.  Today was the first time I signed into iCloud.com with the developer ID and it seemed like it was building out the ID for some reason.  Anyway, thanks!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It's working now. Looks like the developer ID didn't have iCloud Drive initially for some reason. Now it shows up. Today was the first time I signed into iCloud.com with the developer ID and it seemed like it was building out the ID for some reason. Anyway, thanks!!!!!!